# How to add an external product to woocommerce cart page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I am using printful API to create and order the customized products to printful. so in my site i made an 'add to cart' button. when click the button the product will create in printful and user will redirect to woocommerce cart page and see product data which is not actually a product in woocommerce. But I am stuck on how to add an item data like thumbnail, title, price and other data to cart page without making actual product?

don't have idea what to do:(

Answer (score 0):

I believe someone answered it on wordpress forum.

```
https://yourdomain.com/cart/?add-to-cart=[Product-ID]&quantity=[Number-of-items]
```

ref : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/external-add-to-cart-link-for-woocommerce/